# Microsoft Interactions is not recognized in XAML

Tags: wpf, data-binding, blend

**My goal:**
I want to use Interaction Triggers in that way:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Therefore I opened the Nuget and installed this:
[image]

After this the two references (Microsoft.Expression.Interactions and System.Windows.Interactivity) were added to my project. The path of those points to the package directory (Blend.Interactivity.Wpf.1.0.1340.0) in my project folder.

**The problem:**
The namespace is not recognized by Visual Studio. I tried:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

Intelisense is not recognizing any elements inside the i-Tag.

[image]

The .Net version of the project is 4.5.2.
I tried to remove and reinstall the package.
Any ideas what went wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried Clean and Rebuild?

Comment: Yes, I have done this

Comment: How to resolve this issue?